# Why does JS Fiddle give me the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm [testing a Plupload script](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/kXX6L/) when I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function .

Not able to figure out why, I tested with an [example from jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). I get the same error ([se fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/ybqz2/)).

Can anyone  tell me why this isn't working?

Code:

```
$( "div" ).greenify({
  color: "orange"
});

(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
       // Do stuff here
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: You have executed your *Immediately-invoked function expression* that defines the extension after you try to use it :) As you are using `$` outside of it, that IIFE is kind of pointless.

Comment: re: "greenify just a function and it shouldn't matter where I placed it". It is not a `function` declaration, where order would not matter so much, it is an extension method being added to another existing object. Like assigning any other variable, you do need to assign it before you use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have those in the wrong order:

```
// First add the plugin
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
       // Do stuff here
    };
}( jQuery ));

// THEN use it
$( "div" ).greenify({
  color: "orange"
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybqz2/1/)

The general order of things is:

1. `script` tag for jQuery
2. `script` tags for any plugins
3. `script` tag(s) for your code

Comment: I almost want to say DOH! Why does it matter? Isn't `greenify` just a function and it shouldn't matter where I placed it?

Comment: we could also point to the fact that the code is executed in window.onload so even if the OPs code is added in dom ready handler unless the order is changed it will not solve the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ybqz2/5/

Comment: @Steven Only function declarations of the form `function greenify()` are hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope. Even then, the scope here is not the entire file, but just the closure on `$`

Comment: @Steven: Expanding on Eric's comment: JS has function *declarations* and function *expressions*. All of the functions in the code above are created via *expressions*, which happen in the normal step-by-step execution of the code. A function *declaration* is where, outside of all control structures (e.g., not in a loop or `if` block or whatever, but optionally within another function) you have `function foo() { ... }` **without** assigning the result of it to a var or otherwise using the resulting function's value immed. Those are handled upon entry to the scope, not in step-by-step order.